# SKPhysicsJointFixed-SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Unable to create SKPhysicsJointFixed when the bodies collide.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: contact.bodyA, bodyB: contact.bodyB, anchor: contact.contactPoint)
    self.physicsWorld.add(joint)

    let pinJoint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: contact.bodyA, bodyB: contact.bodyB, anchor: contact.contactPoint)
    self.physicsWorld.add(pinJoint)
}
```

FYI- The pin joint is created and its functionality is working fine.
But i want a fixed joint instead of a pin joint.